# Pandas keep column value if True else False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John Doe', 'Jack Bauer???', 'Chris Smith'],
        'flag':['True', 'False', 'True]})[['name', 'flag']]
```

As you can see the first and third names are formatted correctly, but the second name has bad text. I want a new column (or inplace over 'name') that looks like:

```
'name':
'John Doe'
False
'Chris Smith'
```

What is the best way to get this desired result in Pandas? I'm struggling to use masks and apply to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John Doe', 'Jack Bauer???', 'Chris Smith'],
        'flag':['True', 'False', 'True']})[['name', 'flag']]

print (df)
            name   flag
0       John Doe   True
1  Jack Bauer???  False
2    Chris Smith   True

df['new'] = df.name.mask(df.flag=='False', False)
print (df)
            name   flag          new
0       John Doe   True     John Doe
1  Jack Bauer???  False        False
2    Chris Smith   True  Chris Smith
```

If need replace column `name`:

```
df['name'] = df.name.mask(df.flag=='False', False)
          name   flag
0     John Doe   True
1        False  False
2  Chris Smith   True
```

If [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) string `True` and `False` to boolean:

```
df['flag'] = df.flag.replace({'True': True, 'False': False})

df['new'] = df.name.mask(~df.flag, False)
print (df)
            name   flag          new
0       John Doe   True     John Doe
1  Jack Bauer???  False        False
2    Chris Smith   True  Chris Smith
```

Replacing `name`:

```
df['flag'] = df.flag.replace({'True': True, 'False': False})
df['name'] = df.name.mask(~df.flag, False)
print (df)
          name   flag
0     John Doe   True
1        False  False
2  Chris Smith   True
```

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.flag=='True', 'new'] = df.name
print (df)
            name   flag          new
0       John Doe   True     John Doe
1  Jack Bauer???  False          NaN
2    Chris Smith   True  Chris Smith
```

Replacing `name`:

```
df.loc[df.flag=='False', 'name'] = False
print (df)
          name   flag
0     John Doe   True
1        False  False
2  Chris Smith   True
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and flexible answer!

Comment: Glad can help you!